# enable scroll on onload of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in scrolling.When i am at the bottom of my page.I try to scroll up using mouse.page comes down to bottom.This is because still page is loading in bottom.How to enable the scroll after a page loads completely.
 use any event + function.Using jquery or js.

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent the *user* from scrolling and keep the top of the page in view until the page has loaded completely? Or are you trying to scroll programatically?

Comment: @nnnnnn:after pages loads,we should enable the scroll.

Comment: OK, so maybe give the `body` a CSS style of `overflow:hidden`, then in your `onload` change the style to `overflow:auto`? May or may not work in all browsers - I seem to recall in IE you might have to set the style on `html` rather than `body`. This should hide the scrollbars until you want them, though it won't stop the user scrolling by clicking directly on the content and dragging (I doubt that many users would do that though).

Answer (score 0):

Daffodil,
This can usually be achieved by simply putting your script at the bottom of the page.  It won't be called until it is created and it won't be created until the rest of the page is.  Now I'm not positive if you're trying to scroll to the bottom or the top but the code will look something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: @Daffodil,  then you'll need to elaborate further on your issue.  You want no scrolling until page fully loaded?